# Expected float32, got <tensorflow.python.framework.indexed_slices.IndexedSlices of type 'IndexedSlices' instead

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to build a function to perform loss optimzation, I am using Adam optimizer with a learning rate that I will pass in the class itself. However, I was advised to apply clipping to eliminate exploding gradient with clip_by_norm function.

```
def perform_optimization(self):
    """Specifies the optimizer and train_op for the model."""

    # Create an optimizer (tf.train.AdamOptimizer)
    self.optimizer =  tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate= self.learning_rate_ph)
    self.grads_and_vars = self.optimizer.compute_gradients(self.loss)

    clip_norm = tf.cast(1.0, tf.float32)
    self.grads_and_vars = tf.clip_by_norm(t=self.grads_and_vars,clip_norm=clip_norm) 

    self.train_op = self.optimizer.apply_gradients(self.grads_and_vars)
```

I got the error shown in the title, and I traced all my functions in the class and the error was because of this line

```
self.grads_and_vars = tf.clip_by_norm(t=self.grads_and_vars,clip_norm=clip_norm)
```

I am not so sure what I did wrong as this is my first time to use `clip_by_norm`. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

found out that the mistake that the variable `self.grads_and_vars` contains both gradients and variables so I have to make list comprehension to get only the gradients as follows

```
 self.grads_and_vars =[(tf.clip_by_value(grad, -1., 1.), var) for grad, var in self.grads_and_vars]
```

and it worked!